# can't access req.params of app.use() inside middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am trying to build dynamic routes for my application. With the piece of code in app.js looks like this:

```
app.use('/:c_name/api/',middleware);
```

middleware looks like this:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/:m/:c/:a',(req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.params);
var controller = "./fe-ser/leg/fe/cli/"+req.params.c_name+"/main/process/"+req.params.module+"/controllers/"+req.params.controller;
});
```

now to resolve the route inside the middleware, I need the value of `c_name` but I can't access it using `req.params.c_name`. `req.params` only contains `m`, `c` and `a`.

Hence, the question, how can I access `c_name` from my middleware?

Comment: is there a work around may be? I don't want to do it inside app.js because there are hundreds of routes and it just isn't practical. I have to use this middleware

Comment: console.log(req.params.c) or console.log(req.params.m) or console.log(req.params.a) or console.log(req.params.c_name)

Comment: always use a unique keyword before param begins like /product/:id or /product/:gender/type/:material

Comment: Can you please post what you've declared (for initializing your express router) as `var router=express.Router........` ?

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar req.params.c_name is undefined inside the middleware. That's the whole problem. It only contains m,a &c

Comment: @DavidR edited the code

Comment: @properchels Thanks!.. Check my answer below!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will need to add `mergeParams` while initializing your `router` your  which will preserve the `req.params` value

```
var router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad that it is working!.. Feel free to mark it answered! ;-)