# Trouble retrieving data from 'req.params' in Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get my ID of a data model from Express app. In my app.js I've set

```
app.use('/grades/:id/students', studentRoutes);
```

So when I use `/:student_id/show` in any routing `.js` file the route should come like
`/grades/:id/students/:student_id/show` which actually it does but the problem is when I tried to get `req.params.id` I'm getting `null` instead of getting `id`. I was able to get `req.params.student_id` without any issues.

Here is my studentRoute

```
router.get('/:student_id/show', (req, res) => {
  Student.findById(req.params.student_id, (err, foundStudent) => {
    try {
      res.render('students/show', {
        student: foundStudent,
        path: 'student',
        class_id: req.params.id,
      });
      console.log(req);
    } catch (err) {
      res.redirect('back');
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Someone please help me here!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't access req.params of app.use() inside middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245332/cant-access-req-params-of-app-use-inside-middleware)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access params of the parent router, it's required to set [mergeParams](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.router) to `true` when creating a child router:

```
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true })
```